# How to call C# Web Service in Corona (Lua)?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, soap-client

I am trying to call a web service written in C#. Below is client side in corona:

```
local client = require "soap.client"
local ns, meth, ent = client.call {
    url = "http://172.16.1.162:7878/BaksetBilgi.svc", 
    soapaction = "doubler",
    method = "http://titck.kara.com/bask",
    entries = { 
    ......}
```

When I run this code, it gives error :

> module 'soap.client' not found:resource (soap.client.lu) does not exist in archive..

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That module is not part of corona. Looks like it's only 3 files, you could copy them into your Corona project. Note that the language that SOAP service is written in is irrelevant to the client: SOAP is a protocall, if you know how to format your data in HTML then you can do SOAP. Look at any good SOAP tutorial. But I don't know why you wouldn't want to use that library, just copy the files into your project.

Comment: Is there another way to call service?  Or example of it ?